# Ready to pull my hair out Java Queues with objects

Tags: java, object, queue

Can anyone tell me where im going wrong I have three files Person.java Queue.java & Cinema.java, ive managed to do queues without objects Person.java but. I am having trouble implementing with objects.

Heres my Queue.java

```
    public class Queue
{
    private Person[] person = new Person[10];       
    private int rear;

    public Queue()
    {

       rear = 0;                      
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
         return rear == 0;
    }

    public String remove()          //remove String element
    {
        String result = person[0].toString();       //shuffle String elements
        rear--;
        for (int i = 0; i < rear ; i++)
        {
            person[i] = person[i + 1];
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void add(Person x)           //add String element
    {
        if (rear == person.length)
        {
            resize();
        }
        person[rear] = x;
        rear++;
    }  

    private void resize()
    {
        Person[] temp = new Person[person.length * 2];    //resize String array
        for (int i = 0; i < person.length; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = person[i];
    }
        person = temp;
    }
}
```

Then heres Person.java (Object).

```
    public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private int age = 0;

    public Person(String name1, int age1)
    {
        this.name = name1;
        this.age = age1;
    }
}
```

And heres the main java file Cinema.java

```
    import java.util.*;
public class Cinema {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Queue q = new Queue();
        Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
                String name = k.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter Age : ");
                int age = k.nextInt();

                q.add(name);
                System.out.println(name + " joined queue");
    }
}
```

Basically I want a person to join the queue with a name and age and the first person goes to buy the ticket and the age is checked. I can do the check bit its just getting it to read with objects.

Thanks

Comment: From your implementation of `Queue.java` I'm sensing a `Stack` class. Google about "What is Queue"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I see two issues up here :

1. The Queue class seems to be implemented as a Stack rather than a Queue. I would suggest, Google about what queues are .
2. In your main method

   ```
               String name = k.nextLine();
               System.out.print("Enter Age : ");
               int age = k.nextInt();

               q.add(name);
   ```

   Here, `add` method requires a `person` object as its parameter rather than a `String` object.
   The code should be like :

   ```
           String name = k.nextLine();
           System.out.print("Enter Age : ");
           int age = k.nextInt();
           Person p1 = new Person(name,age);
           q.add(p1);
   ```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT!!!**:

For your question in the comment. If you want to return age of the people in the Queue. You first would have to make two getter methods. One inside the Person class & other in the Queue class:

In person class:

```
public int getAge()
{
return age;
}
```

In Queue class:

```
public Person[] getPerson() 
    {
        return person;
    }
```

After writing these functions down. You can have the ages of people in the queue as :

```
Person[] p = q.getPerson(); // q is the Queue object
for(int i=0;i<p.length;i++)
{
 if(p[i]!=0)
  {
   System.out.println(p[i].getAge());
  }
}
```

Hope this helps. if this helps you reach the solution of your problem, do upvote and select the answer as correct one.

Comment: Manage to get that bit working but if I wanted Queue to return the age of the object would do I do public int age() { then code but I cant anything like person.getAge() :(

Comment: @user3004559 : See the EDIT in my answer

Comment: Cheers mate got it working and even added more my self, once I get going in the code it just pops out if you get what I mean. I cant vote up as I don't have enough rep but once I do I will.